# WPF: How to access data from firebase in Task format

Tags: c#, wpf, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im building a server in WPF which uses FireSharp (https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp). Im able to send data to my firebase server and also receive it but the problem is that i get it back as a Task and i cant seem to open it.

Im sending data with this functions

```
private async void Send_Data(FirebaseClient client, int data){
    SetResponse response = await 
    client.SetAsync("Teams/number",data);
    int result = response.ResultAs<int>();
    PushResponse response2 = await 
    client.PushAsync("Teams/number",data);

}
```

And i get the data like so

```
private async Task<int> Get_Data(FirebaseClient client) {
    FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("Teams/number");
    int todo = response.ResultAs<int>();
    return response.ResultAs<int>();
}
```

I get from firebase Task

and i tried doing:

```
Task<int> data = Get_Data(client);
data.Result;
```

Which makes my program crash.

What is the correct way to get data back from firebase?

Comment: Also when i try and see what data it self returns,
data.ToString() returns System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Int32]

Comment: Tasks<T> belong to multitasking and thus there are two common ways to use them: 1. Have a callback function that is being raised on completion. 2. Wait for it to finish (with await). Then use the result as if it was a normal, synchronosu function.